# Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied, (Parameter 'content'), System.ArgumentNullException (Parameter 'input')

Tags: c#, exception, json-deserialization, neo4jclient

I am new to Neo4jClient and I can't seem to get a simple query working.

I have class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfEnrollment { get; set; }
}
```

Inserting into the db works by doing:

```
_graphClient
    .Cypher
    .Create("(user:User $user)")
    .WithParam("user", user)
    .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync()
    .Wait();
```

Where `_graphClient` is just a regular GraphClient with `JsonContractResolver = CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()`.

However, when I try and return all User nodes:

```
var query = _graphClient
    .Cypher
    .Match("user:User")
    .Return<User>("user");
var result = await query.ResultsAsync;
```

I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  System.ArgumentException: Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied.

  First, try and review the exception below to work out what broke.

  If it's not obvious, you can ask for help at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neo4jclient

  Include the full text of this exception, including this message, the stack trace, and all of the inner exception details.

  Include the full type definition of Project.Models.User.

  Include this raw JSON, with any sensitive values replaced with non-sensitive equivalents:

   (Parameter 'content')
   ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'input')
     at System.Text.RegularExpressions.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument arg)
     at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String input, String replacement)
     at Neo4jClient.Serialization.CommonDeserializerMethods.ReplaceAllDateInstancesWithNeoDates(String content)
     at Neo4jClient.Serialization.CypherJsonDeserializer`1.Deserialize(String content, Boolean isHttp)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Neo4jClient.Serialization.CypherJsonDeserializer`1.Deserialize(String content, Boolean isHttp)
     at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.Neo4jClient.IRawGraphClient.ExecuteGetCypherResultsAsync[TResult](CypherQuery query)
     at Project.Repositories.UserRepository.GetAllUsers() in C:\Code\Project\Repositories\UserRepository.cs:line 27
     at Project.Controllers.UserController.Get() in C:\Code\Project\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 26
     at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Removing DateTime from the User type doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: All I see is: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'input')

Comment: Can you try putting parenthesis around the `Match` bit, i.e. `.Match("(user:User)")`

Comment: @CharlotteSkardon parenthesis worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the error is coming from, the code I'll put in below works in LinqPad (and should be fine for a normal C# app). I've tried both the `BoltGraphClient` and the `GraphClient` - and I don't get any errors.

I've tried removing the `DateTime` or `int` properties from the DB, but it simply reverts to `default()` for those values.

Can you try the code below and see if it works - I can't see any problem with your code that is obvious - it looks absolutely fine to me.

---

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    var boltClient = new BoltGraphClient("neo4j://localhost:7687", "neo4j", "neo");
    boltClient.JsonContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    await boltClient.ConnectAsync();

    await DoActions(boltClient, "BOLT");
    
    var httpClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474"), "neo4j", "neo");
    httpClient.JsonContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    await httpClient.ConnectAsync();
    
    await DoActions(boltClient, "HTTP");
}

public async Task DoActions(IGraphClient client, string type)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Performing actions using {type} type of connection.");
    await ClearUsers(client);
    await CreateUser(client);
    
    var users = await GetUsers(client);
    WriteUsers(users);
}

public void WriteUsers(IEnumerable<User> users){
    Console.WriteLine("Users");
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{user.Id}: {user.FirstName} {user.LastName} ({user.Gender}), {user.Email}, {user.DateOfBirth}, {user.DateOfEnrollment}");
    }
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsers(IGraphClient graphClient)
{
    var query = graphClient
        .Cypher
        .Match("(user:User)")
        .Return<User>("user");

    return await query.ResultsAsync;
}

public async Task ClearUsers(IGraphClient graphClient)
{
    await graphClient.Cypher
        .Match("(u:User)")
        .Delete("u")
        .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
}

public async Task CreateUser(IGraphClient graphClient)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        Id = 1,
        FirstName = "Charlotte",
        LastName = "Skardon",
        DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now,
        DateOfEnrollment = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3),
        Email = "a@a.com",
        Gender = "F"
    };

    await graphClient
        .Cypher
        .Create("(user:User $user)")
        .WithParam("user", user)
        .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();      
}


public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfEnrollment { get; set; }
}
```